# Does Natural Explorer's double proficiency apply to perception checks while keeping watch?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, proficiency, terrain

The Natural Explorer class feature is sort of vague about what skill checks count

> When you make an Intelligence or Wisdom check **related to** your favored terrain, your proficiency bonus is doubled if you are using a skill that you’re proficient in.

I emphasized related to, because it doesn't say "while in," so I'm wondering whether keeping watch in your favored terrain counts as related to your favored terrain. This could represent something like being more familiar with what's naturally around, and so you have an easier time spotting what shouldn't be -- i.e. the approaching enemy.

Does it apply?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Yes, this works.

Observing and investigating the area while in your favored terrain is definitely **related** to your favored terrain. This is exactly what the feature was written for.

Comment: While I agree with your interpretation, I can imagine some DMs disagreeing ...?

Comment: How could any DM disagree? Surely keeping watch in your favoured terrain is related to your favoured terrain?

Comment: I think it's vague enough that this interpretation is not obvious. The reason I asked, is that if the rule said "advantage to all wisdom and intelligence checks related to chairs" I wouldn't assume you're better at spotting things just because you're sitting in a chair.

Comment: @NathanHinchey Your analogy isn’t quite there. You’re better at spotting things *in a chair warehouse or factory*.